# How to add items to an array according to its category?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page that is a simulation of a clothing store. The list of clothes displayed is divided into five different categories.

The user has the option to click on the `Add Clothes` button and add a new clothes to the list that already exists.

My question is how to add a new item to the clothing array according to the category that the user chose?

For example, if he chooses to add a hat, add the new item to the hat collection within the array.

Here''s my code I put in CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-flower-1ij9v?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Here's my shop data:

```
const shop_data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Hats",
    routeName: "hats",
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Brown Brim",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png",
        price: 25
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Blue Beanie",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/ypkgK0X/blue-beanie.png",
        price: 18
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Brown Cowboy",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/QdJwgmp/brown-cowboy.png",
        price: 35
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Sneakers",
    routeName: "sneakers",
    items: [{
        id: 10,
        name: "Adidas NMD",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/0s3pdnc/adidas-nmd.png",
        price: 220
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "Adidas Yeezy",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/dJbG1cT/yeezy.png",
        price: 280
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: "Black Converse",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/bPmVXyP/black-converse.png",
        price: 110
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Jackets",
    routeName: "jackets",
    items: [{
        id: 18,
        name: "Black Jean Shearling",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/XzcwL5s/black-shearling.png",
        price: 125
      },
      {
        id: 19,
        name: "Blue Jean Jacket",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/mJS6vz0/blue-jean-jacket.png",
        price: 90
      },
      {
        id: 20,
        name: "Grey Jean Jacket",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/N71k1ML/grey-jean-jacket.png",
        price: 90
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Womens",
    routeName: "womens",
    items: [{
        id: 23,
        name: "Blue Tanktop",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/7CQVJNm/blue-tank.png",
        price: 25
      },
      {
        id: 24,
        name: "Floral Blouse",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/4W2DGKm/floral-blouse.png",
        price: 20
      },
      {
        id: 25,
        name: "Floral Dress",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/KV18Ysr/floral-skirt.png",
        price: 80
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Mens",
    routeName: "mens",
    items: [{
        id: 30,
        name: "Camo Down Vest",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/xJS0T3Y/camo-vest.png",
        price: 325
      },
      {
        id: 31,
        name: "Floral T-shirt",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/qMQ75QZ/floral-shirt.png",
        price: 20
      },
      {
        id: 32,
        name: "Black & White Longsleeve",
        imageUrl: "https://i.ibb.co/55z32tw/long-sleeve.png",
        price: 25
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default shop_data;
```

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your shop data stored? Is it in the application state or somewhere in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a callback function to `DialogSelect` which will take the `item` and the `category` as parameters, then update the state.

In ShopPage create an `addItem` function

```js
addItem = (item, category) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    collections: prevState.collections.map((collection) => {
      if (collection.routeName === category) {
        return {
          ...collection,
          items: collection.items.concat({
            ...item,
            // setting the id to the length of the array
            // can cause problems, use an id generator of
            // some sort
            id: collection.items.length + 1
          })
        };
      }

      return collection;
    })
  }));
};
```

then pass it to DialogSelect

`<DialogSelect addItem={this.addItem} />`

In `DialogSelect` call the callback from `props` when the user is adding an item

```js
const addClothes = () => {
  const item = { product, price, imageUrl };
  addItem(item, category);
};
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-jennings-26byw?file=/src/features/Select/Select.jsx)

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions, the first one would be to pass the results from your DialogSelect component to the parent (ShopPage) by using a callback in the props:

```
<DialogSelect onAddClothes={this.onAddClothes} />
```

Then, in this.onAddClothes function, you can update your collections through a setState() call. Use a findIndex on collections to find the object having "hats" as a routeName and add your item in the items array with a push() call.

The second solution would be to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) in order to have a general store for your application (this could be interesting especially for a shopping website).

Comment: Hey Olivier, I will use the second option, this works perfectly for me. I'm going to try to implement Redux now, as I haven't managed even the basics yet, I thought it best not to say anything about Redux in the question, but now I'm going to try to implement, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi i made a few changes to your code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-babbage-pwmn1

You need to update your state when data send for this I made a function which update the state by category. If the category matches then add the item in the list

```
  addNewClothes = (clothes) => {
    const updatedCollections = this.state.collections;
    updatedCollections.map((collection) => {
      //if collection routerName eques to category
      // then update the collection
      if (collection.routeName === clothes.category) {
        //add new Item in items
        collection.items.push({
          id: collection.items.length + 1,
          name: clothes.product,
          price: clothes.price,
          imageUrl: clothes.imageUrl
        });
        //return updated collection
        return collection;
      } else {
        // return original collection
        return collection;
      }
    });
    //update the state
    this.setState({
      collections: updatedCollections
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hey Defx, that´s works perfectly too, but in the moment, the Asaf's solution is better for me, thank you very much!!!